# How to replace particular tag in xml with textarea

Tags: jquery, xml

I have one xml in that I have tag with following structure <>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<learningBECContentbody>       
    <instructorNoteSay>Pranali When we read a text,
        <a>Pranali</a>
        together. Instead, we pause, or rest,
        <a>Manali</a>
    </instructorNoteSay>
    <instructorNoteSay>Harshila When we read a text,
        we <a>Riya</a>
        do notrun all our words together
        <a>sina</a>
    </instructorNoteSay>
    <instructorNoteSay>When we
        <a>check</a>
        read a text,
        <a>text</a>
    </instructorNoteSay>         
</learningBECContentbody>
```

I want to replace a tag with textarea by using jquery .. can someone please help me out

Comment: What tag do you want replaced?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `replaceWith()` method, try this:

```
$('learningBECContentbody').find('a').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith('<textarea>'+ $(this).text() +'</textarea>')
})
```

Comment: I want whole data of xml and I want convert that particular a tag with textarea for example  Pranali When we read a text,"<textarea>"together. Instead, we pause, or rest,"<textare>"

Comment: @user1527000 `learningBECContentbody` should be replaced with `textarea`?

Comment: You should edit your answer, `$(this).text()` doesn't make any sense as is

Comment: I tried both by using $(this).text() I got text of all <a> tag at the same time ..but I am not getting how to use suggestion of Raminson

Comment: @user1527000 updated answer replaces every a tag with a textarea.

Comment: @user1527000 http://jsfiddle.net/bfZyr/, do you want to everything between the 2 a tags be replaced with a textarea?

Comment: yes and then i want to print whole sentence with that texrarea

Comment: @user1527000 sorry, this requires RegExp and I'm not good at them.

Answer (score -2):

If you prefer RegEx, you can always do this:

```
var xml = // store the XML in here, via an ajax call, or other
var rep = $(xml).replace(/<instructorNoteSay>(.*)</instructorNoteSay>/gi, "<textarea>$1</textarea>");
```

This will find all elements with the tag of instructorNoteSay and take the text inside and put it into a textarea.

Good Luck!

Comment: jQuery has no method `replace()`, and using RegEx to parse/modify DOMs is generally a bad idea.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript, or ahve you forgotten? Of course replace will work. http://jsfiddle.net/P3xAA/1/

Comment: @TurdPile that's not what your code has. In your answer you are indeed calling `.replace` on a jQuery object, and they don't have `.replace`

Comment: @TurdPile - your efforts would be better spent revisiting your code rather than reacting so sulkily to my comment. You are running `replace()` on a jQuery object. Therefore, since jQuery HAS NO `replace()` method, it will generate an error. `replace()` is a method of `String`, not `Object`.